# Complexity of initializing a list

Tags: python

I want to initialize an empty list of given size. I've found the following on SO:
`lst = [None] * n`
What is complexity of this piece of code? Is it constant or linear? If it's linear then what are the constant ways?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creating a `list` of size N will always be O(N) in Python.  If you want to create lists in constant time but with variable length, you'll need to write your own data structure which does it in a "virtual" way.  For example, imagine a class similar to `list` but with an extra member "_virtual_len" which is returned by `__len__()`.  Then when iterating, this special list-like class can iterate over the actual values it contains, plus some number of "empty" values to reach `_virtual_len`.  Constructing such a list would be O(1).

Comment: Thanks! Is there any standart python data structure with such capability?

Comment: OTOH, accessing an element would be O(n) instead of O(1), since it would need to materialize the list at that point.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: I don't think so: the "real" part of the list would be accessed in O(1) like a regular Python `list`, and the "virtual" part would be accessed in O(1) by simply returning the "empty" value.  There is no need to materialize the virtual part.

Comment: How do you know where the real and virtual parts are? You need a separate list to keep track of that, and initializing *that* list is O(n). Maybe I'm being stupid, but I can't see how you can avoid either iterating (which is O(n)) or bookkeeping (which is O(n)).

Comment: Some boundary cases I can imagine are 1) the real part is at the very end, the virtual part is at the beginning; 2) every odd element is real, every even element is virtual.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: I think you're imagining a lot more flexibility than I am.  I'm just imagining the virtual part can be at the end.

Comment: How does that work when I, e.g. assign some value to the last index?