# Is it possible to create a(n uninialized) Python list of n integers in [0,n) in O(1) time?

Tags: python, arrays, time

The following Python code creates a(n initialized) list of *n* nonnegative integers, each of which is at most *n*-1:

```
a = [0] * n
```

I assume that the instruction takes *O*(*n*) time due to the initialization. Is there is a way in Python to obtain a list of *n* integers in *O*(1) time? I don't care whether the list is initialized or not. I just want the time complexity be *O*(1). I also want the list mutable and supporting O(1)-time access and update for the *i*-th entry.  This can be easily done in C via `malloc`. How about Python?

Comment: "This can be easily done in C via malloc"  absolutely NOT. Malloc does not initialize anything. Malloc in c allocates space, but allocated memory is not initialized. It means that if you read an allocated memory value after invoking malloc, you will get an indefinite result. [See also here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45323930/is-malloc-initializing-allocated-array-to-zero)
What I mean is that you are comparing two different things. You cannot say that malloc initializes in 0(1)

Comment: @Wippo, Thanks for your quick reply. Actually, I don't care whether the content is initialized or not. I just want the time complexity be O(1).

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50198421/complexity-of-initializing-a-list

Comment: @joostblack, Thanks for the pointer. However, a virtual list as suggested there is not what I am looking for. For instance, it seems difficult to keep the advantage of a python list of getting/setting the i-th entry of a virtual list in O(1) time.

Comment: No, "uninitalized" doesn't make sense with regards to a Python list. A list of N integers "uninitialized" simply doesn't mean anything.  List objects are not like primitive arrays in C. You really should stop thinking in C terms, Python is a very different language in many respect. Now, you can use something like `numpy` which provides, essentially, an object-oriented wrapper around primitive, multidimensional arrays. And using something like `numpy.empty` might be what you need, although, I don't think that makes any guarantees

Comment: Perhaps it would be better if you told us *what you were actually trying to accomplish* rather than trying to shoe-horn in concepts that don't readily apply to Python from C? I suspect you simply need an empty list

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, Thanks for the suggestion. Basically, I just want something similar to the thing that can be done via malloc in C: Creating a continuous chunk of memory in O(1) time that can store n nonnegative integers, each of which is at most n-1. I want the i-th integer can be accessed/updated in O(1) time.

Comment: @evenodd no, you are telling me *your solution* not what you are trying to do. In any case, such a thing barely makes sense in Python, if you are thinking of things in terms of "chunks of memory" then you are probably not using the right language, or you need to adjust your thinking. You *almost certainly* need one of the built-in containers. You can probably just use a list, but perhaps a `dict` would do as well. Without knowing what you are trying to do, I can only speculate.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, Believe it or not, this is the thing I want to do... I have my own reason. I agree that Python is probably a wrong language for doing this. But, somehow I have no choice...

Comment: @evenodd So, you simple don't want to *share* what you are trying to do. That's ok, but don't pretend otherwise. This is a classic X-Y problem. In any case, what you want is not possible in Python. Python gives you no direct access to memory. Now, CPython might have something in `ctypes` that would allow you to do this, or you can write your own C-extension, or use a library that uses C-extensions (e.g. the `numpy.empty` suggestion I had above).  Those are your choices. Almost certainly, all of those would give you no real benefit over using a `dict` or a `list`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, Thanks for understanding. A simple answer saying that this is impossible in Python would actually be also quite good.

Comment: [Python/C memory management documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/memory.html) may contain some useful information

Comment: @Wippo, cool. I will take a look.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you, use NumPy to create a list if you want speed. Just create a list using NumPy with different values you can initialize it with zeros or random values also by just calling different function. This is the fastest way I know to get the list.

```
import numpy as np
my_array = np.zeros(n)
```

Comment: that is *an initialized array*. Also, numpy arrays *are nots lists*. They have different performance trade-offs.

Comment: @halcyoona, Thanks for the suggestion. Somehow I still want the creation time independent of the length n of the list.

Comment: @evenodd why don't you just use an empty list?

Comment: @ juanpa.arrivillaga, Good question. An empty list would make, e.g., a[n//2] = 1 expensive.

Comment: @evenodd how about an empty `dict` then?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, dict uses hash function. The worst-case time can be pretty bad.

Comment: @evenodd so what? Have you actually encountered a performance issue?  Is the worst case even relevant? If a `dict` is too slow for you, then probably, you need to use a different language than CPython.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, I understand the fundamental difference between C and Python. Somehow I still want the worst-case performance be guaranteed to be independent of n.

Comment: @evenodd  list1 = range(n) you should give this a try.

Comment: @halcyoona it needs to be mutable. And ranges express.. well *ranges* of integers.

Comment: Indeed, I need a mutable one.